# Keep login with x-ms-webview in Windows 10

Tags: javascript, cookies, win-universal-app, windows-10

I'd like the user to navigate to different URL's inside my Windows 10 App. He should be able to login and if he restarts the app, the login still should be valid. This is my code:

```
 // Prepare the request message
var webview = document.querySelector("x-ms-webview");
var httpRequestMessage = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage(
      Windows.Web.Http.HttpMethod.get,
      new Windows.Foundation.Uri(site));

// Get the cookies from the cookieManager
var filter = new Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
var cookieManager = filter.cookieManager;
var cookies = cookieManager.getCookies(new Windows.Foundation.Uri(site));
var cookieString = "";


cookies.forEach(function (value) {
    cookieString += value.name + "=" + value.value + ";"
})

// Remove the last ';'
cookieString = cookieString.substr(0, cookieString.length - 1);

// Add those cookies to the http Header
httpRequestMessage.headers.cookie.tryParseAdd(cookieString);
webview.navigateWithHttpRequestMessage(httpRequestMessage);
```

But still not working. Is there even a way to enable this using the x-ms-webview?

Comment: Is it only failing after restarting the app? Or is it failing without restarting the app too?

Comment: @kiewic It's actually only when I restart the app. While the app is open, the cookies are active, even without the code above.

Comment: Then, maybe it is a session cookie. Can you look into the [`HttpCookie.Expires`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpcookie.aspx) property within your `forEach` loop?

Comment: I just checked it - actually all cookies expire right to the moment the Page has been loaded.